# Regarding state flow plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have one query that is I have one file which is named as abc.state that is ending with state extension it functionality is to manage the flow as we have struts.xml in struts for webflow,

the abc.state file contains the following thing..

```
<state name="firststate">
    <event name="abc" next="@def"/>
    <event name="@def" pi="javaclass1" next="@init,@cfg"/>
    <event name="@cfg" pi="javaclass2" next=",nextstate"/>
  </state>
```

The above thing indicates that global event abc would happen then user defined even @def will be called which will execute a javaclass1 and the javaclass1 will return a value 0 or 1 and dependind upon it @init or @cfg will be called , Please advise is there any eclipse plugin in which i can see the state flows in a flow chart order of the whole state flow